# read a csv file and validate whether input parameter is in the csv file then bypass the purge process otherwise initiate purge process using python

Tags: python, for-loop, validation, read.csv, notin

sample csv file:

```
test.csv
process_cd
ramsize
dbsize
protocal
random
```

function will be called with below parameters

```
self.complete_stage_purge_process(self.targetCnxn, self.targetTable, self.processCode)
```

sample process codes:

```
test
protocal
forensic
```

each time function is called need to read the csv file for those process codes and if process code matches then bypass internal delete call

```
def complete_stage_purge_process(self, target_cnxn, stage_table, process_cd):
       
            delete_sql = "delete from " + schemaName.STAGE.value + "." + \
                stage_table + " where run_pk in (" + run_pk_sql + ")"
            try:
                trgt_cursor = target_cnxn.cursor()
                trgt_cursor.execute(delete_sql)
                target_cnxn.commit()
                self.logger.debug("deletes processed successfully ")
                target_cnxn.close()
            except:
                self.logger.exception('Error in processing deletes')
                raise
        else:
            self.logger.debug('purge process is not required for this process')
```

how to achieve that csv read in loop

Tried with below piece of code but the code is still going to purge process and not running the process code search  in loop

```
 non_purge_process_file = open(self.file_path)
        reader = csv.reader(non_purge_process_file)
        for row in reader:
            if process_cd in row:
                self.logger.debug("Do not perform stage purge process.")
                return
            else:
                delete_dt = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
                delete_dt = str(delete_dt)
```

Comment: so for each`code in self.processCode call that fuction unless the code is in sample csv?

Comment: if the input parameter value is present in csv file then dont call the function, otherwise that is when input parameter value is not present in csv file then call delete sql. Hope I am clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved solution to above problem using below approach:

```
def check_process_cd(self, process_cd):
        self.logger.debug(datetime.now())
        self.logger.debug('check_process_cd')
        purge_process_flag = 0

        reader = csv.reader(purge_process_codes_file)
        for row in reader:
                if process_cd == row[0]:
                    self.logger.debug("Perform stage purge process.")
                    purge_process_flag = 1
        return purge_process_flag
```

based on flag perform the function call

```
if self.purge_process_flag == 1:
            self.complete_stage_purge_process(self.targetCnxn, self.targetTable, self.processCode)
        else:
            self.logger.debug('Do not perform purge process')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv


def validate_and_purge(input_param, csv_file):
    found = False  # flag to indicate whether input_param is found in the CSV file
    with open(csv_file, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if input_param in row:
                found = True
                break
    if found:
        return True
    
    return False
```